# UICollectionViewLayout - 3 cells in 2 columns

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to create a UICollectionView with a 7-cell repeating layout that looks like this:

[image]

However, with CollectionViewLayout, I can't seem to get the 6th and 7th cell into the same column.

Here's the relevant code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds.width
        let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let spaceBetweenCells = flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        var adjustedWidth = collectionViewWidth - spaceBetweenCells

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 0 {
            return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewWidth)
        }

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 1 || indexPath.row % 7 == 2 || indexPath.row % 7 == 3 {
            adjustedWidth = collectionViewWidth - (spaceBetweenCells * 2)
            return CGSize(width: floor(adjustedWidth / 3), height: floor(adjustedWidth / 3))
        }

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 4 {
            adjustedWidth = collectionViewWidth - spaceBetweenCells * 2
            return CGSize(width: floor(adjustedWidth / 3) * 2 + spaceBetweenCells, height: floor(adjustedWidth / 3) * 2 + spaceBetweenCells)
        }

        if indexPath.row % 7 == 5 || indexPath.row % 7 == 6 {
            adjustedWidth = collectionViewWidth - spaceBetweenCells * 2
            return CGSize(width: floor(adjustedWidth / 3), height: floor(adjustedWidth / 3))
        }

        let width: CGFloat = adjustedWidth / 2
        let height: CGFloat = width;
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I've even tried using a smaller height for the last two cells, to make sure the height wasn't an issue. Thanks for any help.

---

**Update** 
I got it to work via UIStackViews, albeit pretty annoying.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use UIStackView? Seems lot of pain giving the size for each and every item in a collection view.

Comment: You mean use a combination of UIStackViews instead of a UICollectionView? I would have to manage enqueuing/dequeuing the views, then no? That seems like a lot more pain.

Comment: I meant a combination of both.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be an easy task by just using the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s `sizeForItem` method. You would have to use

```
if indexPath.row % 7 == 0 || indexPath.row % 7 == 4 {
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: collectionViewWidth)
}
```

And then within the `cellForItemAt` method:

```
if indexPath.row % 7 == 4 {
    // Provide a UIStackView with your required layout
    // Or maybe even you could provide a smaller UICollectionView with just 3 cells, but that seems like overkill.
}
```

Comment: I'll try this -- I'm sure it will work. But, I'm curious if that's the right approach here. Thanks for the idea!